# What are the date standards that can be inputted to `date -d`?

Tags: bash, date, format, standards

I am writing a wiki for a bash script I wrote, and one of the optional argument is a date which will be passed onto `date -d $DATE`. What would be the best way to explain what types of date formats are acceptable? Per man page as well as trial and error, 07/10/2015 and 20150710 are acceptable, but 07102015 and 150710 are not. Also, arguments like "yesterday", and "2 days ago" are valid. Is there an umbrella term that describe these types of date formats?

Comment: Your script does not need to be as permissive as GNU `date`; either impose your own (well-defined) date format, or simply refer the user to the GNU documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a lot on who your users are.  For reasonably experienced users, the description in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html):

> This section describes the textual date representations that GNU
>   programs accept.  These are the strings you, as a user, can supply as
>   arguments to the various programs.

suggests writing something like "a date in a format accepted by GNU programs".